# How can i compare inside a script bash?

Tags: bash, git, shell

I want to check if i am stay in the dev branch, my file .sh have this content:

```
let current = GIT branch --show-current

if  current == "dev"
```

but it does not worked, i am getting this error:

```
line 3: let: =: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let` is an obsolete command for performing arithmetic. You want a command substitution. Then you need to use a specific command to perform the comparison; you can use either `test` or `[[ ... ]]`

```
current=$(git branch --show-current)

if [ "$current" = dev ]; then
    echo "On dev branch"
fi

if [[ $current = dev ]]; then
    echo "On dev branch"
fi
```